# Wait for 2 events. If one of them happens, do something

Tags: r, events, wait

How can I wait for 2 events in R so that if one of them happens, do something?

I want to wait for a window to be closed, with `tkwait.window(myWindow)`, or wait for a variable to be changed, with `tkwait.variable(myVar)`.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
blablabla_1
tkwait.variable(myVar) | tkwait.window(myWindow)
blablabla_2
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: or how can I set action before closing window --> so that I will change the value of `myVar` just before closing `myWindow`... So, only `tkwait.variable(myVar)` will be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a binding to your toplevel window to trigger something when that window gets closed (i.e., "destroyed"). What gets triggered is a change in the value of the variable you're waiting on.

Here I assume that your window is called `myWindow` and that the variable is called `myVar`.

```
    tkbind(myWindow, "<Destroy>", function() tclvalue(myVar) <- 2)
```

Above, `myVar` is assigned a `2`, but you could use pretty much any value, as long as it leads to a change.